# White-list of URI protocols for XSS prevention?

Tags: url, protocols, xss, href

If I allow a user to post a URL to a page, then I create an `<a>` tag with that URL, I have to first check to see if it is safe.

I know that `javascript:` protocol would be un-safe as it would run code from the URL from the user.

I know that `http:` and `https:` protocols are OK.

I also know that there are more protocols, like `ftp:`, so, is there a white-list I can copy from?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML specification has [whitelist of schemes for `registerProtocolHandler()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#whitelisted-scheme) that could be a starting point.